# How to update the Doxygen plugin in Qt Creator 10.0.0 for successful use

Tags: qt, plugins, qt-creator, documentation, doxygen

How to use the Doxygen plugin compatible with Qt Creator 4.13.2 in Qt Creator 10.0.0?

I am currently trying to use the Doxygen plugin in Qt Creator 10.0.0. However, I have encountered compatibility issues with the plugin version available.

[image]

After running the Qt Creator 10.0.0 this message appears :

[image]

I have tried installing a previous version of the plugin and updating it, but the Doxygen plugin does not show the updated version of it when I update qtcreator.

[image]

Here are the details of my setup:

- Qt Creator version: 10.0.0
- Doxygen plugin version : compatible with Qt Creator 4.13.2

Can someone please provide guidance on how to successfully use the [Doxygen plugin](https://github.com/fpoussin/qtcreator-doxygen/releases) in Qt Creator 10.0.0?

Comment: The plugin developer has no time to [port the plugin](https://github.com/fpoussin/qtcreator-doxygen/issues/47#issuecomment-1046014471) to the latest versions of QtCreator. So until someone work on the code to support QtCreator 10, it will not work.